# short and char type in Java

Tags: java

According to the Java standard the `short` and `char` types both use 2 bytes so when I code something like:

```
char ch = 'c';
short s = ch;
```

There is an error saying "possible loss of precision". What am I missing here?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`char` is unsigned, `short` is signed.

So while they are both 2-byte long, they use the sixteenth bit for different purposes.

The range of the `char` type is 0 to 2^16 - 1 (0 to 65535).

The `short` range is -2^15 to 2^15 - 1 (−32,768 to 32,767).

Comment: a related question why cant java convert from short to char?

Comment: Because they don't cover the same range.

Answer (score 12):

The difference is that `char` is unsigned, `short` is signed. Thus, half the range of values of `char` is too big to be represented as a `short` (and of course, in symmetry, `char` cannot represent any of the negative values `short` can).