# What is the difference between Short and Character apart from processing?

Tags: java

For what I know:

- "bytewise", it looks like they are the same (they are both 2 bytes long);
- `Character`, however, has more processing to it (static `.isLetter()` method and others, etc).

While my questions may sound dumb, here they are:

- unless my first assumption is wrong, why are there primitive types `char` and `short` since they have the same "internal length` and, anyway, there are no unsigned primitive types in Java?
- `Short` is `final`, if it weren't, could `Character` have extended `Short`?

**EDIT**: answer given and I was wrong: there *is* one unsigned primitive type in Java and that is... `char`.

**EDIT 2**: @PatriciaShanahan also mentions that in *arithmetic* operations, a `char` behaves like an unsigned 16bit integer, just like a `short`. And this includes left shifts, that is, the sign bit *is* carried along, just like for `short`.

Comment: This might shed some light: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058859/short-and-char-type-in-java

Comment: As far as unsigned primitives, you are also forgetting `boolean`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik not really, `boolean` isn't a numeric type at all in Java (it can't be cast to any of the numeric types, nor vice-versa) so the signed/unsigned distinction doesn't apply.

Comment: char represents either characters (not just letters) or numbers, depending on how it is used. As an operand in an arithmetic expression, it is an unsigned 16 bit integer.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan interesting observation!

Comment: @fge So where did you get the "no unsigned primitive types" idea? I would like to track down the origin, to see if it is possible to get it corrected.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan not from the JLS since I didn't read it in detail... In fact, I play a lot with network packets, where unsigned types are common; I was fearful of using `char` for 16bit elements; even though I knew it was two bytes long, I was unsure how it was handled at low level (due to `Character` vs `Short`), so I held up to `short` and made up with Java's idiocy with primitive type conversion (namely, carrying the sign bit on a cast). This question raised essentially from "why `short` and not `char`", and I investigated from then on. Not enough, it seems!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The essential difference is that `short` is signed, `char` is unsigned.

```
public class CharVsShort {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    short ffShort = (short)0xFFFF;
    char ffChar = (char)0xFFFF;

    System.out.println("all-1s-short = " + (int)ffShort);
    System.out.println("all-1s-char  = " + (int)ffChar);
  }
}
```

prints

```
all-1s-short = -1
all-1s-char  = 65535
```

The [Java Language Specification section 4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2) states that

> The integral types are `byte`, `short`, `int`, and `long`, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit **signed** two's-complement integers, respectively, and `char`, whose values are 16-bit **unsigned** integers representing UTF-16 code units

(my bold).  It also gives the types' ranges explicitly as

- `byte`, from -128 to 127, inclusive
- `short`, from -32768 to 32767, inclusive
- `int`, from -2147483648 to 2147483647, inclusive
- `long`, from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807, inclusive
- `char`, from '\u0000' to '\uffff' inclusive, that is, from 0 to 65535

Comment: Hmwell, no. There are no unsigned primitive types in Java. Unless you meant something else by that?

Comment: +1 for identifying `char` correctly as an unsigned primitive type.  @fge is wrong here.

Comment: +1 `char`s range from 0 to 65535 whereas `short`s range from -32768 to -32767.

Comment: I've seen this idea of "no unsigned primitive types" in Java a couple of times recently, despite the glaringly obvious counter-example of char. Perhaps @fge could clarify where it is coming from.

Comment: I don't know where it's coming from, but I know where to point them to prove it's not right. :) [JLS 4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1): `The integral types [include] char, whose values are 16-bit unsigned integers representing UTF-16 code units.`

Comment: OK, I stand duly corrected... So, `char` is really the only unsigned primitive type in Java then?

Comment: @IanRoberts, would you mind adding a link to that JLS section referred to here?

Comment: @fge I've linked and inserted the relevant content directly.

Comment: @IanRoberts Thanks! Slight nit, but the range itself isn't quite enough. That range could be implemented as a wider, signed field (think of an `int` modded to 65536). A `char` is truly unsigned, which has ramifications, e.g. for sign extension with shift operations.

Comment: @yshavit that is no slight nit to me... Since I have been working quite a lot with unsigned values (due to network processing, where packets can have 8bit, 16bit unsigned values) and had to play with masks all along to get Java to behave, this comes as quite a surprise that `char` does not extend the sign bit on shifts.

Comment: @fge Wait, I think I'm an idiot. The lhs of a shift operation is only an int or long, not a char ([15.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19)). Char's quirks are more evident in type promotions (5.1).

Answer (score 3):

They're currently incompatible, and that could never be changed.  But to guess why they were *originally* different -- it's probably a *really good idea* to have different types for numerical data and letters, even if their contents work exactly the same way, just to avoid getting them mixed up.  That would be *bad.*

Comment: Strangely enough, though (I have tested and the commenter is right), @PatriciaShanahan mentioned that in arithmetic operations, a `char` behaves like a `short`, basically. How special is `char` internally for this to be?

Comment: Not at all, since arithmetic on both `short` and `char` is actually `int` arithmetic.  It just promotes them both to `int` internally.

Comment: OK, so the treatment is really up to the JVM, except for arithemtic operations? I mean, `Character` has special rules for display etc, but leaves that to the JVM core for arithmetics?

Comment: Of course.  `char` is a primitive type, and `Character`, like all the wrapper types, is just a very, very simple wrapper around its corresponding primitive type.

Answer (score 0):

Facts about short and char to be known:

1. a char primitive variable can never be assigned to a short without explicit casting.
2. a short primitive variable can never be assigned to a char without explicit casting.

   ```
   char c = 'c';
   short s = c; // will cause a compiler error

   short sh = 10;
   char ch = sh; // will also cause a compiler error
   ```
3. A short constant i.e defined with keyword final can be assigned to a char only if the value fits into a char ( 0 - 65535), and vice versa is also true.
   For the examples in item1 and item2. Below fixes the errors.

   ```
    final char c = 'c';
    short s = c; // compiles without any issues.

    final short sh = 10;
    char ch = sh; // compiles without any issues.
   ```

However, below fails because char is unsigned i.e can only handle positive literals.

```
     final short sh = -1;
     char ch = sh; // compiler error is thrown
```

to fix the error, an explicit case will be needed.

```
     final short sh = -1;
     char ch = (char)sh; // compiler error is thrown
```