# Java - Int,Short,Char binary operations

Tags: java, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

As im currently aware the following is correct:

- char 8 bit value e.g 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
- short 16 bit value e.g 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
- int 32 bit value e.g 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

I know the above sounds idiot proof but i want to desribe every step.

So  i have the values 1 and 29 which are both 8 bits if im correct.

```
 1: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
29: 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1
```

Now as these are 8 bits i can do the following

```
char ff = (char) 1;
char off = (char) 29;
```

So thats me storying my two values.

I now want to concation these values so it looks like
1 2 9 in binary that would be: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1

Im currently doing:

```
short concat = (short) (ff | off)
```

But get the result 29 when it should be 285 as the binary would be

32768 16384 8192 4096 2048 1024 512 256 128 64 32 16 8 4 2 1

0      0     0     0    0    0   0   1   0   0  0  1 1 0 0 1

Where the hell im going wrong :(?

-- UPDATE CODE SOLUTION --

```
byte of= (byte) 29;
byte fm1 = (byte) 1;
char ph1 = (char) (fm1<<8 | of);
```

or is
        short ph2 = (short) (fm1 <<8 | of);

Whats better as there both 16 bit?

```
System.out.println((int)ph1);
```

Comment: char is two bytes in Java, use byte instead

Comment: And `29` is not `00011001`, it is `00011101`.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058859/short-and-char-type-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to shift the bits left, by 8.

```
short concat = (short) (ff <<8 | off)
```

The pipe is the bitwise or, so you just end up putting the same bits on the same place, putting 1s on places were either the first, or the second char has a 1.

Comment: Great answer updated by code, is that the most elegant way please see update

Comment: with ff and off "char"? I'm surprised!

Comment: You should simply accept the man's answer, rather than repeat the solution in your question.

Comment: Sorry updated and missed a bit, Please read about char and short there both 16 bit correct? But whats better to store it in andwhy?

Comment: I would accept the answer the now but i have to wait 7 minutes accordding to stack overflow

Comment: @Aubin, IIRC, the type is converted to 'int' internally when shifting like this. So the char ends up as int.

Answer (score 1):

char is two bytes

byte is one byte

```
byte ff  = (byte)  1;
byte off = (byte) 29;
short concat = (ff << 8)|off;
```