# How can write() method output a character

Tags: java, input

write() method's general form

```
void write(int value)
```

it takes an int value as parameter but prints out a character without casting

```
int b;
b='A';
System.out.write(b);
```

can anyone explain how write method does that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short because chars are just numbers, you can cast between `int` and `char` and fundamentally nothing changes (as long as you don't start messing with negatives and numbers  possibly outside the range of the char data type).

More precisely, chars are like "unsigned shorts", [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5058859/short-and-char-type-in-java), and obviously you can work without too many problems between "unsigned shorts" and integers.

You can do things like:

```
char c = 'c';
int x = (int) c;
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(x);
System.out.println((char) x);
c = (char) (c + 1);
System.out.println(c);
```

This prints:

```
c
99
c
d
```

So when you call `write('A')` it automatically casts 'A' to its corresponding integer `65` and it works the same as if you called `write(65)`.

And what happens if you call `write(65)`? Well that the byte `65` is sent to the console, and this being a text console is interprets the bytes as characters, so it prints 65 as its corresponding character 'A'.

Fundamentally, 'A' is just `1000001` in binary, which is 65 in decimal. You are just calling `write` with 65 which is `1000001`, or 'A' when interpreted as a character of the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: sorry but it all seems very confusing..is java a very hard programming language to study or am i being just dumb??

Comment: This is not Java specific, your question is very fundamental to how data and programming works, and the answer would be the same for many other languages like C or C++. Do not worry if you don't completely understand what "short", "casting", and "binary" means. What you need is a good introduction to programming book. And Java is a fine strong and simple language to start with.

Answer (score 0):

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#write%28byte[]%29](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilterOutputStream.html#write%28byte%5b%5d%29)

It seems that the general form of the write method takes an array of byte instead of an int value :

```
public void write(byte[] b)
           throws IOException
```

Comment: System.out is a PrintStream and the `void write(int)` method [exists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#write(int))

Comment: Yep. I didn't meant to say that it doesn't exist. The PrintStream's write method override the FilterOutputStream's one though... Maybe it uses it when you send something that it is not an integer. Dunno

Comment: No, methods with diferent number of type of arguments are different methods that do not override each other. It is very common to have classes with several methods with the same name/return but different arguments. There's no conflict.

Comment: @Oliboy50 oh..thnks.my java textbook has put out only one form of write() method.

Comment: @sweet_revathy569 Get a better book, and in any case learn to use the Javadoc. That's what it's for.

Comment: @sweet_revathy569 Note that this answer is incorrect, even if it were correct it does not explain what calling `write('A')` and executing a `write(byte[])` means or why would that possibly work. Which it doesn't because that is not what it's happening.

Comment: @EJP do u mind telling any good book i am refering herbert schildt's book. using internet to study java is kind of difficult coz it is not always available 2 me

Comment: @sweet_revathy569 I am not familiar with Herbert Schildt's Java book, but made the mistake of buying a C++ book by him, back when I was switching from C to C++. Fortunately, my C knowledge told me that it had serious problems. You can download the API documentation from e.g. (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/java-se-7-doc-download-435117.html)

Comment: @sweet_revathy569 It's important to have the documentation at hand, however you won't learn from that alone and while I can't personally recomend a specific book [here](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/home/chapter1.pdf), are [some](http://math.hws.edu/eck/cs124/downloads/javanotes6-linked.pdf), [results](http://www.oracle.com/events/global/en/java-outreach/resources/java-a-beginners-guide-1720064.pdf) with a quick "introduction to programming in java pdf" google search, which is the kind of material you need.